# How to connect to socks tunner through openvpn server?

Tags: networking, openvpn, socks

I have some socks5 proxy and I am able to create tunnel using https://github.com/ambrop72/badvpn/wiki/Tun2socks.
Also I have openvpn server on the same machine.

The question is how to implement **client -> openvpn -> tun2socks (socks5)** connection?
How to add, like, default gateway for openvpn server?
I've created tun2socks tunnel using

```
ip tuntap add dev tun51 mode tun user root
ifconfig tun1 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
/root/badvpn-build/tun2socks/badvpn-tun2socks --tundev tun51 --netif-ipaddr 10.0.0.2 --netif-netmask 255.255.255.0 --socks-server-addr x.x.x.x:port
route add (x.x.x.x socks server ip) (y.y.y.y eth0 gateway) metric 5
```

For openvpn - I used https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install, so I have 10.8.0.0 network: gateway is 10.8.0.1 and client is 10.8.0.2.

So what routes should I add? Or what settings should I apply?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using policy based routing.

```
ip route add default via 10.0.0.2 table 101
ip rule add from 10.8.0.2 table 101
```